# Add Footer in WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on my client's website and i have to add custom footer to the theme.

```
http://businessumpire.com/
```

The theme doesn't allow to add widget in the footer, is there any way to to add widget in 4 blocks so i can add menu, latest post etc in the footer via widgets.

Answer (score 3):

You should do that overriding the theme or even better making a child theme. Then you should register with `register_sidebar()` wordpress function a sidebar for your footer and call it from your footer template via `dynamic sidebar()`. This way you could add all the widgets available to your footer. To add the menu in the footer you can call `wp_nav_menu()` in the footer`. If you dono't know how to do this you can try to download a theme which has this functionalities and try to adapt your code from there.

Comment: Well it will be more helpful with any plugin

Comment: Maybe you can use 'Custom Headers and Footers". I haven't tried it but it may be useful.